# How to check group permissions in Django view?

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have created two groups `group1` and `group2` and assigned users accordingly. I have found that i can decline access in templates using

```
{% if perms.app1 %} // app1 is a app in project
///show something
{% endif %}
```

In the above code, am just check if the user has any permission related to the app and if true it will show and if false it will hide. This is how it works i believe.

Now, how to implement this on views ? How to just give app name and check if the user has permission to the view functions in view.py ? Adding a list of permissions is not a good practice i believe, is there a way to just give app name to check permissions ?

And I already have a role check decorator :

```
def is_agent(login_url=None):
    actual_decorator = user_passes_test(lambda u: u.role == 1)
    
    if actual_decorator:
        return actual_decorator
    else:
        raise Http404
```

So is there i can add things to decorator or how to handle it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to define `group_required` as decorators:

```
def group_required(*groups):

    def decorator(function):
        def wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            if request.user.groups.filter(name__in=groups).exists():
                return function(request, *args, **kwargs)
            raise PermissionDenied

        return wrapper

    return decorator
```